Nightwatch test don't fail when NoSuchElementError is thrown
I inherited an automation test suite in Nightwatch/Cucumber and encountered an interesting issue. When a step fails due to an element not being found or an assertion error, the scenario continues running and eventually marks as 'passed'.
I tried adding abortOnAssertionFailure: true and abortOnElementLocateError: true to my config file, but it didn't make any change to the test run. Ideally, the scenario should abort as soon as anything fails, and the scenario should be marked as 'failed'. A day of research didn't give me an answer. I'd appreciate any pointers.
